# HttpSessionListener sessionDestroyed() method not getting called in Websphere 8.5.5.12 cluster(after upgrade from 8.5.5 to 8.5.5.12)

Tags: java, cluster-computing, session-timeout, websphere-8, httpsession

We have implemented the session time out by implementing HTTPSessionListener class in our web application. The web application was deployed in Websphere 8.5.5 in a cluster with Memory to Memory replication (peer to peer replication topology). 
The time out was working fine.
Now recently we have upgraded the websphere to 8.5.5.12 and the time out has stopped working ie; sessionDestroyed method is not getting called.

Following is the sample code:

```
    public class TestSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {    
@Override
public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("Session created");
}
@Override
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
System.out.println("Session Destroyed");        
}}
```

Web.xml

```
    <session-config id="SessionConfig">
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.test.app.TestSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The issue that we are facing is that the sessionCreated method is getting invoked but the sessionDestroyed is not getting invoked.

The same  application when deployed in a non clustered environment is working in 8.5.5.12 and also working in 8.5.5 in a clustered environment.

Any config which has to be done in Websphere ?

Comment: If it stopped working after upgrade then I'd suggest opening PMR in IBM Support.

Comment: I think I have a similar problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: Not yet! Will update once resolved.